# How to use preventDefault in contenteditable divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable, preventdefault

[This is an example on CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hCgnA)

Here's the code anyway:

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="mydiv"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#mydiv").keydown(function (evt) {
    if (evt.which == 13) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert('event fired');  
    }
  });
});
```

Why won't the `evt.preventDefault()` method work?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `preventDefault` call just keeps the default event handler from running. If you want to skip any code after the point where you have `evt.preventDefault()`,  put a `return false` after it.

```
$(function () {
    $("#mydiv").keydown(function (evt) {
        if (evt.which == 13) {
            return false; // <-- now event doesn't bubble up and alert doesn't run
            alert('event fired');  
        }
    });
});
```

Also, as mentioned by squint, you can use `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: But I thought it was bad practice to use `return false`.

Comment: @think123 `return false` is equivalent to calling both `evt.preventDefault();` and `evt.stopPropagation();`

Comment: You have it backwards. `preventDefault` doesn't keep the event from bubbling. That's what `stopPropagation` does.

Comment: And @clav you can't really `alert` after `return`ing... just saying.

Comment: @think123: It's just that jQuery breaks the standard behavior by making `return false;` also stop the event bubbling. If you don't want to do that, then just call `evt.stopPropagation()` manually.

Comment: @squint you're right, I meant to just take the `preventDefault` out of there, return false should be all he needs.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté just left his `alert` in there to demonstrate the obvious point that everything after the `return` statement doesn't run and the event doesn't bubble either.

Comment: Yes, @roXon has worded it better. `=]` Anything that comes in the same control flow after a `return` statement is considered unreachable code.